# non-Dedekind Domain in which every ideal is generated by at most two elements

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, nt.number-theory

Does anyone know of such a domain?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may find Matlis' paper [The Two-Generator Problem for Ideals](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/michigan-mathematical-journal/volume-17/issue-3/The-two-generator-problem-for-ideals/10.1307/mmj/1029000474.full) to be interesting, as its main theorem concerns the class of integral domains in which every ideal is generated by two elements.

It was proven by Cohen (in *Commutative Rings with Restricted Minimum Condition* ) that an integral domain with the property that there exists an integer $n$ such that every ideal can be generated with fewer than $n$ elements must be Noetherian and of Krull dimension 1.

Say that an integral domain R has property **FD** if every finitely generated torsion free R-module is  direct sum of modules of rank 1. Moreover, say that R has property **FD locally** if R<sub>M</sub> has property FD for every maximal ideal M of R.

**Theorem** (simplified form) - Let R be an arbitrary integral domain. Then every ideal of R can be generated by two elements if and only if R is a noetherian ring that has property FD locally.

Answer (score 13):

[**Edited** to restrict to the case of quadratic orders. --PLC]

Take any non-maximal order of a quadratic number field. This is not Dedekind because it fails to be integrally closed in its field of fractions.  Every ideal is a free abelian subgroup of rank at most $2$.

For example: $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}].$

I hope this answers your question. For further reading on Dedekind domains, and non-maximal Orders, I highly recommend the chapter on it in Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory.

Comment: This certainly works for any order in a quadratic number field, but I believe it fails in general.  (This was a problem on a problem set I did some time ago: http://modular.math.washington.edu/129-05/homework/4/4.pdf but I don't have the example I came up with on hand.)

Comment: You are probably correct, I have only been thinking about quadratic extensions lately, and didn't think to check the general case. I'll try to think of a counter-example myself.

Comment: Alison is right.  Consider the function field analogue: the number of elements needed to generate the maximal ideal of a point on an affine curve is at least the dimension of the Zariski tangent space, which can be arbitrarily large at a singularity.  Here is an explicit number ring example: Let A=Z[2^{1/3}], let R=Z+2A, and let m=2A, viewed as an R-ideal.  Then m/m^2 is 3-dimensional over R/m=F_2, so m is not generated by fewer than 3 elements.

Answer (score 9):

By way of comparison, Dedekind domains are characterized by an even stronger property, sometimes referred to colloquially as "$1+\epsilon$''-generation of ideals.  Namely:

Theorem: For an integral domain $R$, the following are equivalent:
(i) $R$ is a Dedekind domain.
(ii) For every nonzero ideal $I$ of $R$ and $0 \neq a \in I$, there exists $b \in I$ such that $I = \langle a,b \rangle$.

The proof of (i) $\implies$ (ii) is such a standard exercise that maybe I shouldn't ruin it by giving the proof here.  That (ii) $\implies$ (i) is not nearly as well known, although sufficiently faithful readers of Jacobon's *Basic Algebra* will know it: he gives the result as Exercise 3 in Volume II, Section 10.2 -- "Characterizations of Dedekind domains" -- and attributes it to H. Sah.  (A MathSciNet search for such a person turned up nothing.)  The argument is as follows: certainly the condition implies that $R$ is Noetherian, and a Noetherian domain is a Dedekind domain iff its localization at every maximal ideal is a DVR.  The condition (ii) passes to ideals in the localization, and the killing blow is dealt by Nakayama's Lemma.

Comment: H. Sah was probably Chih Han Sah. Obituary: http://www.nytimes.com/1997/08/18/nyregion/chih-han-sah-62-mathematics-professor.html?pagewanted=1

Comment: Thanks, Carl.  That seems very reasonable, although I have no way of knowing for sure.  I did a MathSciNet search for C.-H. Sah and found plenty of papers, although nothing which jumped out as containing this result.